# Nested vertical RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an issue making 2 nested vertical RecyclerViews. I know this isn't a great pattern, but these are the application requests.

I have a parent RecyclerView, and when a card expands it should scroll to top and in the expanded part, I have another RecyclerView (a list of locations).

The problem is that I couldn't pass the scroll event from the parent, to the child RecyclerView. I read about the NestedScrollingChild interface and tried to enable nestedScrolling in child, but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no, it is just not possible, you should give up of this thought and try something to **simulate** the same effect

Comment: fixed it. never start coding with that premise. everything is possible.

Comment: Hey Cristian, this one is not working for me... are you able to post more code? The child recyclerView is simply not picking up scrolling touch events. The log of CHILD TOUCH is going off but the child recyclerView is not scrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following code on my main RecyclerView adapter. Works perfectly.

```
 holder.locationsList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```